# ruby return an array of sub elements using map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following structure:

```
"countries": [
  {
    "states" :[
      {
        "name" :"Texas",
        "id": "a1"
      },
      {
        "name" :"Nebraska",
        "id": "a1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    "states" :[
      {
        "name" :"New York",
        "id": "a1",
      },
      {
        "name" :"Florida",
        "id": "a1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return an array of all the states from above.
Here is what I tried:

```
 countries.map { |country| country.states.map { |state| state.name } }
```

But  it returns only the first 2 statest 'Texas' and Nebraska.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `countries.map { |country| country['states'].map { |state| state.name } }`

Comment: Your "structure" looks off with few errors.  How did you generate it?

Comment: you have missed brace `{` here before `states`: `},

    "states" :[`

Comment: Sorry, my sturucture had a bunch of other things which I didn't want to paste. so it became a typo

Comment: are you sure this is not a `JSON` object?? you probably need to supply your data structure else it would be difficult to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you structure wasn't right, so corrected:

```
countries = [
      {
        "states" => [
          {
            "name" => "Texas",
            "id"=> "a1"
          },
          {
            "name"=> "Nebraska",
            "id"=> "a1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "states" => [
          {
            "name"=> "New York",
            "id"=> "a1",
          },
          {
            "name" =>"Florida",
            "id"=> "a1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Ruby wasn't accepting ":" for strings for some weird reasons. Like this(which isn't working):

```
countries = [
      {
        "states": [
          {
            "name": "Texas",
            "id": "a1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Nebraska",
            "id": "a1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "states": [
          {
            "name": "New York",
            "id": "a1",
          },
          {
            "name" :"Florida",
            "id": "a1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

For this, you can do:

```
countries.map{ |c| c["states"].map{|s| s["name"]}}.flatten
#=> ["Texas", "Nebraska", "New York", "Florida"]
```

Or if you get the repetitive values then:

```
countries.map{ |c| c["states"].map{|s| s["name"]}}.flatten.uniq
#=> ["Texas", "Nebraska", "New York", "Florida"]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Surya's answer, it is the same solution. Just wanna show how I write it:

```
countries.map{|x|x['states']}
         .flatten
         .map{|x|x['name']}
```